# In what quadrant are the reciprocal ratios of tan, cos and sine positive?

Tags: trigonometry

If tan is negative in the third quadrant, would its reciprocal ratio, cot, be positive?

Comment: No. The reciprocal of $a\ne0$ is $1/a$. They have the same sign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An angle whose terminal side is in the third quadrant has positive tangent: Since each of $\cos \theta < 0$ and $\sin \theta < 0$ in the third quadrant, $$\sin \theta <0, \cos\theta < 0 \implies \tan\theta = \frac {\sin \theta}{\cos \theta} > 0.$$ Invariably, this also means $$\cot\theta = \dfrac 1{\tan\theta} = \dfrac{\cos \theta}{\sin \theta} > 0$$

$\tan \theta < 0 $ if and only if the terminal side of an angle lies in the second or fourth quadrant. And $\tan \theta \implies \cot \theta < 0$, so this is also true of $\cot \theta$.

$$\text{For any }\,\theta, \;\;\operatorname{sign}(\tan\theta) = \operatorname{sign}(\cot \theta)$$

Answer (score 0):

Since $x\cdot \cfrac 1x=1\gt 0$, any number has the same sign as its reciprocal.

Note that "reciprocal" is different from "inverse" - and these two are easy to confuse with trigonometric functions.

For example we normally write $\tan ^{-1}x = \arctan x$ not $\tan ^{-1}x = \cot x$. Some care is therefore required in interpreting questions and applying intuition, especially when you are learning the functions for the first time.